# Sutherland-Hodgman polygon clipping not working

Tags: matlab

I want to find common part between two polygons. I use [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman_polygon_clipping#MATLAB_.2F_Octave) algorithm

The code works on the example from the link. But I try to use it on my example (simple rotated square) it does not work:

```
subject =[434.0774  239.3566
          414.1666  237.4698
          412.2798  257.3806    
          432.1906  259.2674
          434.0774  239.3566];


clipPolygon = subject;

clipPolygon = clipPolygon + 2;

clippedSubject = sutherlandHodgman(subject, clipPolygon);                    

figure;
plot(subject(:,1),     subject(:,2), 'b-');
hold on;
plot(clipPolygon(:,1), clipPolygon(:,2), 'r-');
```

The two squares are shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ6qK.jpg) and it clearly shows that it should be possible to clip one square with the second one as they overlap.

The problem is that `clippedSubject` is empty. The algorithm did not find common part or clipped part. Why is that? Can anyone clarify what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is a requirement in the function `inside` (read the source):

```
%inside() assumes the boundary is oriented counter-clockwise
function in = inside(point,boundary)
```

This means that this set of vertices will lead to an error:

```
subject =[ 24.  19.
            4.  19.
            4.   47.    
           24.   47.];
```

whereas this won't:

```
subject =[ 24.  19.
            4.  19.
            4.   7.    
           24.   7.];
```

One solution is to change the order of vertices, for instance like this:

```
subject = subject(end:-1:1,:);
```

You can add a check to see in which way the vertices are running and modify their order if necessary.